# How to set limit of max length to TextBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have set limit maxlength="9" for TextBox, code is below:

```
<asp:TextBox  ID="txtEIN" runat="server" CssClass="search-box" maxlength="9" type="number"  pattern="[0-9]*"  placeholder="EIN without dash"></asp:TextBox>
```

But the problem is we can enter more than 9 number, but I need to set max limit to 9.

Answer (score 2):

The `MaxLength` property will not work when using a "number" input (i.e. `type="number"`). You could consider setting the `max` and `min` attributes to handle the range :

```
<asp:TextBox ... type="number" min="1" max="999999999"></asp:TextBox>
```

For a complete solution, you would probably want to rely on some client-side code to explicitly restrict what can/cannot be entered into the element or consider using a third-party component that would handle this type of behavior for you.

Comment: No.... i am getting same problem...... it is taking more than 9 digits......i need to set exact 9 digit suppose if user enter morethan 9 digits it should not display in text box......... Thanks for helping me.....

Answer (score 2):

you can set MaxLength Property of TextBox

```
textBox1.MaxLength = 9;
```

Comment: still It is  taking morethan 9 digits ...... please help me if any other solution is der please let me know

Comment: Use this regular expression in your aspx.cs file and its validate with your textbox 
ValidationExpression=" [A-Z, a-z,0-9]{9}"